# How to create multiple (6) plots with ggplot and save them to a pdf file?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I have a matrix (`pred_matrix`, dim = 1e6, 250), the rows are "pixelstacks" of 250 NDVI values of a Landsat scene, from which i did a "fuzzy cmeans" classification witch 6 centers (classes), stored in the list `results`. I want now to plot a random subset of each class of the 1e6 rows. This is my quick and dirty code so far:

```
random_index <- floor(runif(10000, 1, 1e6+1))
random_cluster <- results[[6]]$cluster[random_index]
random_pred_matrix <- pred_matrix[random_index, ]
dates_subse_after_pred <- rdn_num[rm_na_pred_df]

random_res <- cbind(random_pred_matrix, random_cluster)
random_res <- t(random_res)
random_res <- cbind(c(dates_subse_after_pred, 1), random_res)

df_1 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==1)])
df_2 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==2)])
df_3 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==3)])
df_4 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==4)])
df_5 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==5)])
df_6 <- data.frame(random_res[1:250,c(TRUE, random_cluster==6)])


df_1.long <- melt(df_1, id.vars = 1)
df_1.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_1.long$X1)
df_2.long <- melt(df_2, id.vars = 1)
df_2.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_2.long$X1)
df_3.long <- melt(df_3, id.vars = 1)
df_3.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_3.long$X1)
df_4.long <- melt(df_4, id.vars = 1)
df_4.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_4.long$X1)
df_5.long <- melt(df_5, id.vars = 1)
df_5.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_5.long$X1)
df_6.long <- melt(df_6, id.vars = 1)
df_6.long$X1 <- as.Date(df_6.long$X1)


ggplot(df_1.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "lightblue")

ggplot(df_2.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "blue")

ggplot(df_3.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "lightgreen")

ggplot(df_4.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "green")

ggplot(df_5.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "pink")

ggplot(df_6.long) +
  geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), color = "red")
```

After this i have just hit 6 times the export button in rstudio and inserted it all in a word document...

Is there a way to do this in a loop? Or even produce a final pdf containing the 6 plots?

Comment: Maybe `pdf("myplots.pdf"); ggplot(df1.... ; ggplot(df2.... ; ggplot(df3.... ; etc; deve.off()`. **Or** we could rbind all dataframes, and use facet. **Or** we could use cowplot package.

Comment: I found this blog post helpful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/


Also, when you use ggplot and dev.off() make sure you wrap your ggplot() code in a print statement:

`print(ggplot())
dev.off()`

Answer (score 0):

## Separate file

I think what you are after is having the following six times in your code.

```
ggsave("filename.png", # or pdf if you like  
 plot = last_plot(), # or give ggplot object name as in myPlot,
 width = 5, height = 5, 
 units = "in", # other options c("in", "cm", "mm"), 
 dpi = 300)
```

For example, 
    library(ggplot2)

```
p1 <- ggplot(df_1.long) +
 geom_line( aes(x = X1, y= value, group = variable), 
  color = "lightblue")

 ggsave("df1.png", plot  = p1,  dpi = 300)
```

## All in one

If you want **all the six files in one pdf**, then first do

```
pdf("file_name.pdf")
# do your ggplots here
p1
p2
p6 
dev.off()
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Rstudio I would recommend writing your code in a Rmarkdown file and then exporting to pdf directly.